# Copying Data's from workbook to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone have the Macro code for copying from one excel workbook sheet data's to another excel workbook sheet but that should be date and time conditioned?

ex:

```
Date         Time      Fruits
4/22/2009    7:30:34   Apple
4/22/2009    7:30:37   Orange
4/22/2009    7:31:19   Mango
4/22/2009    7:31:37   Grapes
4/22/2009    7:32:37   Banana
4/22/2009    7:33:37   xyz
4/22/2009    7:34:37   ABC
```

Here I need to copy from 4/22/2009 7:30:37 to 4/22/2009 7:33:37 fruits information to another workbook sheet including date and time.
Please.

Comment: Do you really want to do this using Python (as your tagging suggests), or are you looking for Excel VBA macro? Maybe retagging your question draws some answers.

Comment: You are right. I am looking for macro code in Excel VBA not in python.
please.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the built-in Advanced Filter function to achieve that.

In Excel 2007 - Data > Sort & Filter > Advanced

In Excel 2003 - Data > Filter > Advanced Filter